# Why is fct_inorder not presenting my factor in order of appearance?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I am extremely new to R and coding in general, so please be patient with me! I have looked everywhere for the solution but everything I have tried hasn't worked or I haven't understood it, so I would appreciate any help you could give me.

I am trying to make a dot plot such that the colors correspond to a range of fold change values and the size of the dot corresponds to the p-value. I start by passing in a csv file with four columns Genes, Concentration, fold change, and p-value. Below is some sample data and the code I have been trying to generate a dot plot with concentration on the x-axis, genes on the y-axis and each dot color corresponding to fold change (but I want to specify a range of values corresponding to one color as below) and size of the dot is p-value.

```
genes <- c('ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN')
concentration <- c('PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR2.4', 'PR2.4','PR2.4', 'PR2.4','PR2.4','PR2.4', 'PR3.6', 'PR3.6','PR3.6', 'PR3.6','PR3.6','PR3.6','PR1.2T', 'PR1.2T','PR1.2T', 'PR1.2T','PR1.2T', 'PR1.2T', 'PR2.4T', 'PR2.4T','PR2.4T', 'PR2.4T','PR2.4T', 'PR2.4T', 'PR3.6T', 'PR3.6T','PR3.6T', 'PR3.6T','PR3.6T','PR3.6T')
foldchange <- c(577.19, 2.642, -697.90, 50.23, 12.582, -30.542, -15.376, 30.674, -1.973, -5.324, -132.761, 146.678, 500.19, 2.233, -656.90, 49.23, 13.582, -80.542, 577.19, 2.642, -697.90, 50.23, 12.582, -30.542, 577.19, 2.642, -697.90, 50.23, 12.582, -30.542, 577.19, 2.642, -697.90, 50.23, 12.582, -30.542)
pval <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3,1,1,4,4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
data <- data.frame(genes, concentration, foldcahnge, pval)

f <- fct_inorder(genes)
g <- fct_inorder(concentration)

# now make dot plot using ggplot2 
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=concentration, y=genes, size=pval)) + labs(y="Gene") +
     geom_point(alpha = 0.9) + geom_point(aes(colour = cut(foldchange), c(Inf, 500, 250, 
                                         100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, -2, 5, -10, -25, -50, 
                                         -100, -250, -500, -Inf)))) + 
     scale_color_manual(name = "fold change", values= c("(500, Inf]" = "firebrick4", 
                                                        "(250,500]" = "firebrick", 
                                                        "(100,250]" = "red3",
                                                        "(500,100] = "red2", 
                                                        "(25,50]" = "red",
                                                        "(10,25]" = "firebrick2", 
                                                        "(5,10]" = "firebrick1", 
                                                        "(2,5]" = "rosybrown1", 
                                                        "(-2,2]" = "gray98"
                                                        "(-5,-2]" = "lightskyblue",
                                                        "(-10,-5]" = "deepskyblue", 
                                                        "(-25,-10]" = "dodgerblue2", 
                                                        "(-50,-25]" = "dodgerblue4", 
                                                        "(-100,-50]" = "blue"
                                                        "(-250,-100]" = "blue3"
                                                        "(-500,-250]" = "darkblue"
                                                        "(-Inf,-500]" = "navy"),
                     labels = c("500", "250", "100", "50", "25", "10", "5", "2", "-2", "-5", "-10", "-25", "-50", "-100", "-250", "-500"))
p + scale_size(range = c(1,4), breaks = c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("pval >0.05", "0.01<pval<0.05", "0.001<pval<0.01", "pval<0.001")
```

Here, I have the same concentrations of the same drug, but on different cell lines, indicated by nothing after the concentration or by a "T" for the "T" cell line. I am having an issue where one of the concentrations are out of order, but the others are fine. When I run this, it returns a dot plot in which the order of the columns are "PR1.2", "PR2.4", "PR2.4T", "PR3.6", "PR1.2T", "PR3.6T". I want them to be in cell line order: "PR1.2", "PR2.4", "PR3.6", "PR1.2T", "PR2.4T", "PR3.6T". Can anyone explain why my concentrations are not in the correct order and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fct_inorder` only changes the order of the levels of the factor, it does not actually make it an "ordered factor" (see [`?factor`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html). `ggplot` will sort factors alphabetically unless it is an ordered factor.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code that make it hard to pin down the specific error though, since as is it doesn't run. A few that I ran into: typo on `foldcahnge` in the data frame creation, missing close quote in `scale_colour_manual` for `(500,100]`, extra parentheses at the end of `geom_point`, `f` and `g` are not actually in `data` so they don't get plotted. I suggest you try to clean this up to run in a new R session to catch these errors, since it is difficult to figure out the real problem otherwise

Answer (score 1):

There are some typos in your code - if you correct these and make some minor changes it appears to me that your code works as expected:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

genes <- fct_inorder(
  f = c(
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN'
  ),
  ordered = TRUE
)
concentration <-
  fct_inorder(
    f = c(
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T'
    ),
    ordered = TRUE
  )
foldchange <-
  c(
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    -15.376,
    30.674,
    -1.973,
    -5.324,
    -132.761,
    146.678,
    500.19,
    2.233,-656.90,
    49.23,
    13.582,
    -80.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542
  )
pval <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
data <- data.frame(genes, concentration, foldchange, pval)


# now make dot plot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = concentration, y = genes, size = pval)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(foldchange,
                              breaks = c(
    500,
    250,
    100,
    50,
    25,
    10,
    5,
    2,
    -2,
    -5,
    -10,
    -25,
    -50,
    -100,
    -250,
    -500
  )))) +
  labs(y = "Gene") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "fold change",
    values = c(
      "(500, Inf]" = "firebrick4",
      "(250,500]" = "firebrick",
      "(100,250]" = "red3",
      "(500,100]" = "red2",
      "(25,50]" = "red",
      "(10,25]" = "firebrick2",
      "(5,10]" = "firebrick1",
      "(2,5]" = "rosybrown1",
      "(-2,2]" = "gray98",
      "(-5,-2]" = "lightskyblue",
      "(-10,-5]" = "deepskyblue",
      "(-25,-10]" = "dodgerblue2",
      "(-50,-25]" = "dodgerblue4",
      "(-100,-50]" = "blue",
      "(-250,-100]" = "blue3",
      "(-500,-250]" = "darkblue",
      "(-Inf,-500]" = "navy"),
    labels = c("500", "250", "100", "50", "25", "10", "5", "2", "-2", "-5", "-10", "-25", "-50", "-100", "-250", "-500"),
    breaks = c(500, 250, 100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, -2, -5, -10, -25, -50, -100, -250, -500))
p + scale_size(breaks = c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("pval >0.05", "0.01<pval<0.05", "0.001<pval<0.01", "pval<0.001"))
```

[image: example_1.png]

It was difficult to find the typos in your original code due to the formatting - if you are using RStudio, you can reformat/reindent your code using Menu>Code>Reformat Code / Menu>Code>Reindent lines, and it makes things like a missing comma easier to see.

### Edit

If you want to specify the order of a factor (e.g. "genes") you can use base R `factor` instead of forcats `fct_inorder`. E.g.

```
genes <- factor(x = c(
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN',
    'ABC',
    'CDE',
    'EFG',
    'HIJ',
    'JKL',
    'LMN'
  ), levels = c(
    'LMN',
    'JKL',
    'HIJ',
    'EFG',
    'CDE',
    'ABC'
  ),
  ordered = TRUE
)
concentration <-
  fct_inorder(
    f = c(
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR1.2',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR2.4',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR3.6',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR1.2T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR2.4T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T',
      'PR3.6T'
    ),
    ordered = TRUE
  )
foldchange <-
  c(
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    -15.376,
    30.674,
    -1.973,
    -5.324,
    -132.761,
    146.678,
    500.19,
    2.233,-656.90,
    49.23,
    13.582,
    -80.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542,
    577.19,
    2.642,
    -697.90,
    50.23,
    12.582,
    -30.542
  )
pval <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
data <- data.frame(genes, concentration, foldchange, pval)


# now make dot plot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = concentration, y = genes, size = pval)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(foldchange,
                              breaks = c(
    500,
    250,
    100,
    50,
    25,
    10,
    5,
    2,
    -2,
    -5,
    -10,
    -25,
    -50,
    -100,
    -250,
    -500
  )))) +
  labs(y = "Gene") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "fold change",
    values = c(
      "(500, Inf]" = "firebrick4",
      "(250,500]" = "firebrick",
      "(100,250]" = "red3",
      "(500,100]" = "red2",
      "(25,50]" = "red",
      "(10,25]" = "firebrick2",
      "(5,10]" = "firebrick1",
      "(2,5]" = "rosybrown1",
      "(-2,2]" = "gray98",
      "(-5,-2]" = "lightskyblue",
      "(-10,-5]" = "deepskyblue",
      "(-25,-10]" = "dodgerblue2",
      "(-50,-25]" = "dodgerblue4",
      "(-100,-50]" = "blue",
      "(-250,-100]" = "blue3",
      "(-500,-250]" = "darkblue",
      "(-Inf,-500]" = "navy"),
    labels = c("500", "250", "100", "50", "25", "10", "5", "2", "-2", "-5", "-10", "-25", "-50", "-100", "-250", "-500"),
    breaks = c(500, 250, 100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, -2, -5, -10, -25, -50, -100, -250, -500))
p + scale_size(breaks = c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("pval >0.05", "0.01<pval<0.05", "0.001<pval<0.01", "pval<0.001"))
```

[image: example_2.png]